# Handling a new exception in an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, exception

I have a situation similar to the following:

```java
/** Get a list of records */
public ArrayList<Record> foo() throws BazException{

    // Create the list
    static ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();

    // Use MyLibrary to load a list of records from the file
    String str = SomeoneElsesLibrary.loadData(new File("mydata.dat"), new DataLoader(){

        // will be called once for each record in the file
        String processRecord(Record r){

            // if there's no "bar", invalid record
            if( ! r.hasField("bar") ){
                throw new BazException();
            }
            records.add(r);
        }
    });
    return records;
}
```

**Obviously this doesn't work**, because `SomeoneElsesLibrary` has no idea what a `BazException` is. I also can't say `processRecord() throws BazException` because then the prototype would no longer match. I'm starting to think that my overall structure for this implementation is wrong. (I'm recovering from a bout of Node.JS addiction and have to re-learn <del>some</del> most Java patterns.) How would I restructure my code to make it more idiomatic Java?

Pseudocode is fine, or even just a description. Also, don't feel like you need to use an anonymous inner class, like I did in my first go at it; I'm just looking for "the Java way" to do this.

Comment: Can't you declare `BazException` as Unchecked one?

Comment: There are (hacky) ways to throw exceptions that aren't declared in the throws clause

Comment: Does the library have an Exception which can wrap your own as that would be the `cause`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception refers to the method can throw it, not to a class (SomeoneElsesLibrary).

There are two types of exceptions, checked (subtype of Exception) and unchecked (subtype of RuntimeException). The checked must be declared explicitly in the signature of the method that can throw it. The unchecked can propagate without being declared in the signature of the method and without being handled by no try/catch block.

Generally checked are used when the caller of the method that raises the exception can remedy it, the unchecked otherwise.

You can handle the **unchecked** exception in foo() method by a try/catch ...

```
public ArrayList<Record> foo(){
    static ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();

    try{
       SomeoneElsesLibrary.loadData( ... );
    } catch (BazException be){ // you just handle the exception here
    }

    return records;
}
```

... or not

```
public ArrayList<Record> foo(){
    static ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();

    // if SomeoneElsesLibrary.loadData raise the BazException
    // it is propagated to the caller of foo()
    SomeoneElsesLibrary.loadData( ... );

    return records;
}
```

Instead a **checked** exception must always be handled.

Comment: So if I throw my `BazException` within the call to `loadData()`, catch it, then throw it again, I'll be able to allow `foo()` to throw the `BazException`. Nice explanation, thanks much.

Comment: If BazException is unchecked (extends RuntimeException) can be directly propagated to the caller of foo() in wich there will be a try/catch block to handle it.

Comment: Ok. My new version throws BazRuntimeException, catches it, and then throws BazException (which is no longer a RuntimeException) so that anything that calls `foo()` is required to handle BazException.

Comment: Look better above. For a better understanding see the Java documentation.

Comment: Right, I do understand. The problem is though that I want anything that calls `foo()` to be required to handle it, and if I simply allow the subclass of `RuntimeException` to propagate then there will be no compiler error if the code that calls `foo()` does not handle it.

Comment: So if that's what you want, use only a checked exception, two is not that elegant (this made me upset :D). Find your way. Methods that throw the exception must declare it in the signature, loadData, foo, processRecord. Then Catch it in the caller of foo. Managing an exception means take care of it, with a try/catch or declaring it in the signature.

Answer (score 5):

Ryan, ensure that your BazException is an extension of the RuntimeException (unchecked exception) rather than Exception (checked one).

Otherwise, as you must have probably noticed, the compiler will complain about not handling your own exception.

For more information, have a look to some information about unchecked exceptions (i.e. RuntimeException or Error):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html